# Issue downloading apyori in python

Tags: python

Here is the error I am getting. I have installed apyori but it keeps saying that the module does not exist. When I list my packages in python it is included

[image: This shows the error I am getting when I try to run my code]

Comment: Do you have jupyter notebook installed in the activate environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try `conda install jupyter` in your activate environment. Close this notebook and restart it. You should be able to import it then.